# Prestashop, display information in function of product ID

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I use Prestashop 1.4 (for requirements of a client) but I need to use a css class in function of the ID of a product.

I try this :

```
<header class="header {if $page_name == 'index' || $page_name == 'product' && $product->id_product== 2}transparent{/if}">
</header>
```

But that's don't work. I try to get the subcategory #2 from home category. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<header class="header {if ($page_name == 'index' || $page_name == 'product') && $marty.get.id_product== 2}transparent{/if}">
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry test with : <header class="header {if ($page_name == 'index' || $page_name == 'product') && $smarty.get.id_product== 2}transparent{/if}">
</header>